# Does windows7 and vista come with preinstalled msxml3.dll

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-xp, msxml3

Do windows 7 and windows vista come with preinstalled msxml3.dll or should i use the newer versions? If so will msxml6 work on windows xp and win2k without installing any additional files?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes MSXML3 is shipped with Vista and W7 (along with MSXML6 in so-called side-by-side installation).

You can install MSXML6 on the following Windows versions

1. Windows 2000 Service Pack 4
2. Windows Server 2003;
3. Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1;
4. Windows XP Service Pack 1;
5. Windows XP Service Pack 2

Source: [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=993c0bcf-3bcf-4009-be21-27e85e1857b1).